# Filter and exclude weekends row in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `CSV` file with the following data.

```
Date(IN GMT), Value
01.01.2017 00:00:00,  1.15430
01.02.2017 00:00:01,  1.15120
01.03.2017 00:00:02,  1.12450
01.04.2017 00:00:03,  1.12330
01.05.2017 00:00:04,  1.12620
....,....
12.31.2017 23:59:59,  1.14620
```

I want to remove the weekend's date so that I only work with weekday values. The date is in GMT.

I want to exclude the weekend's data point entirely. I just want the weekday values. How can I do it with Pandas?

***The other replies on the Stackoverflow does not answer it correctly, because:***

Here's what I did:

```
df['Date(IN GMT)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date(IN GMT)'])
df[df['Date(IN GMT)'].dt.weekday < 5]
```

and I get:

```
Date(IN GMT), Value
2019-05-04 20:57:00,  1.1216 
2019-05-04 20:58:00,  1.1216 
2019-05-04 20:59:00,  1.1215 
2019-07-04 21:00:00,  1.1214 
2019-07-04 21:01:00,  1.1214 
2019-07-04 21:02:00,  1.1215 
2019-07-04 21:03:00,  1.1215
```

If you look above, after `2019-05-04 20:59:00,1.1215` there is the value `2019-07-04 21:00:00,1.1214`

It skipped several hours of data and went to the next date(by skipping weekends)...

Comment: Remove the 5th and 6th day of the week, since python uses zero based indexing: `df[df['Date'].dt.dayofweek < 5]`. But first convert your columns to datetime: `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`

Comment: @Erfan - please see my updated questions. The answer does not work properly.

Comment: Maybe you have a timezone issue? I.e. if you add 3 hours it would all make sense (goes up to right before midnight starts on the Saturday, and starts again right at midnight on Monday). Maybe try `to_datetime(..., utc=True)` .

Comment: It is skipping about 24hrs.

Comment: I see, voted for reopen @alkasm

Comment: Wait is it skipping 2 months instead of 2 days?

Comment: The date is formatted as `Y:D:M`, so its skipping 2 days but not exactly 2 days in terms of hours.